# Authenticating With User ID and Pin using Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, sqflite

This is my first question so forgive me if there is a mistake in formatting or anything else.

I am trying to make an app in flutter and I need a login solution for that. Currently, I am being able to sign-in users using email and password, but I want to sign them in using a PIN that they set up while sign-up.

I went through the documentation of sqflite and shared preferences but I am unable to understand how they could help me.

When signing up, the users are assigned a UID. I am thinking of storing the UID, Name, Email, and some basic user details in a database, and upon opening the app check if a database exists and take the course of action according to that.

I have tried various methods using sqflite, but nothing seems to work for me. If anyone could guide me as to what is the next step that I should take, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you please explain the difference between the password, which you are currently using for login, and the PIN, which you want to use?

Comment: So I have created a form that will first take up a user's email and password for sign up. After the user sign's in, he will need to set a 4 digit pin which could then be used instead of a password. Something similar to logging into windows systems. When the user enters the pin, the code must check if there is database in the system and then use the pin along with the user id to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

For everything regarding user authentication, I recommend using a service such as [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) instead of a local database using sqflite or shared preferences. It‘s completely free unless you got a lot of users and allows your users to sign in on multiple devices. There‘s a variety of login methods such as a combination of email and password or via Google. You can store user related data in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore), for instance.

Comment: We are using an API on both the website and my app so that we have a common database and since the website uses AWS we do not have any option to start using firebase now.

Comment: So why don’t you store the PIN in your database like the password? As an advantage, the user would be able to reset the PIN using his password. Besides, storing data in a local database isn’t the most secure way to do it, especially if you’re using shared preferences. Did you take the Android Keystore into consideration?

Comment: We are storing the Pin in the database online but to login using the PIN wouldn't I require to store the user ID in the local storage, because if I enter the pin, what account will it check against? That is the problem that I am facing and hence wanting to store the user ID and PIN in a local database. As an example, if I store the PIN in the online database and then the user enters the PIN in his phone, how will I be able to authenticate it against his account? If I am wrong here, please correct me.